Is it possible to ensure git is case-sensitive on a repository level?
Context
A little context, to set up why I'm asking this question. .NET MAUI imposes a requirement on some files: "File names must be lowercase, start and end with a letter character, and contain only alphanumeric characters or underscores". Going deeper into that would be off-topic for the question. This limitation wasn't imposed in Xamarin (.NET MAUI is "The evolution of Xamarin.Forms"). In upgrading an app from Xamarin to .NET MAUI, it's necessary to change the file names to match the requirements.
Example Problem
The important part here: I, and others on my team, work with Windows. Git for Windows seems to be case-insensitive by default, to match Windows' file system. I've already solved my issue locally by setting core.ignorecase false, which allowed me to rename the files, but on others' machines where core.ignorecase is true, Git doesn't recognise that any rename occurred, and certain operations will leave a commit that builds on my machine seem erroneous on someone else's.
Non-Answers
I'm already aware of the ignore case configuration option, however that's part of the git configuration, which can differ from user to user. Asking every developer to set core.ignorecase in .git/config is, at best, inconvenient.
Question
Is there a method, within git, to ensure that a repository is treated as case-sensitive, regardless of user configuration or OS?

Hello, would a solution on the central repository (if any) suitable? I'm thinking hooks or CI pipelines.

Thanks for the comment, @YSC - while this wouldn't be a viable solution in my specific use case, I appreciate the idea for anyone else coming along this question who might benefit from it, and potentially for my own future use!

I think the best solution would be a hook on the canonical repository that rejects all incoming changes that contain filenames with upper-case letters. That doesn’t answer the question but it seems like it would solve the problem.

↑ But in practice a lot of code conventions use capital letters (like Java files). So what then? A hook that rejects changes that introduce new files that would icase-conflict with existing once.
